# Truncate string in cpp (preprocessor)

Tags: preprocessor, fortran

I am using cpp with some fortran source code that is compiled with a maximum line lenth of 72 characters.  `__FILE__` works well, but occasionally expands to a long string such that the output of cpp has lines longer than 72 characters.  Is there some pre-processor magic I can use to truncate `__FILE__`?  (Either to a fixed size or to get a basename.)

Answer (score 3):

Why not compile allowing your Fortran source code to be longer then 72 characters?   Most compilers have an option for this, e.g., -ffixed-line-length-none for gfortran. It shouldn't be a problem unless columns past 72 are being used for comments.   Originally columns 73 to 80 were used for line numbers to sort punched cards -- obsolete!!   If you have to, revise the current code using a program to strip off characters past column 73.

Comment: Hm, but eventually he might run into the 132 character limitation? CoCo would do wrapping, but I think it does not have something like __FILE__.

Comment: The 132 limit applies in the free-form layout of Fortran >=90.  Since the question mentioned a line length of 72, I suppose that the fixed-form layout of FORTRAN 77 is being used.  In that layout, the gfortran option -ffixed-line-length-none means that "the entire line is meaningful".  "-extend-source" for ifort will only go to 132 columns, so this could be a problem depending on the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

According to stanadards, C/C++ preprocessor does not have features that allow truncating strings.

My 2 cents.